# Guidelines for permissible maximum linearly-independent cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: software-design, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

For software engineering metrics, what are some guidelines on the maximum permissible linearly-independent cyclomatic complexity? For a properly designed module, what is the upper-bound on cyclomatic complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation in the documentation of the tool NDepend concerning [method Cyclomatic Complexity](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC) is:

- Methods where CC is higher than 15 are hard to understand and maintain.
- Methods where CC is higher than 30 are extremely complex and should be split into smaller methods (except if they are automatically generated by a tool).

*For a properly designed module, what is the upper-bound on cyclomatic complexity?*

CC applies well on methods because a method is a unit of code flow understanding. There are other metrics to estimate the classes and modules (as a grape of classes) design and complexity like for example:

- [Lack of Cohesion Of Methods](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#LCOM)
- [Relational Cohesion](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#RelationalCohesion)
- [Distance from main sequence](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#DitFromMainSeq)

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*

Comment: For tool generated methods, what is the recommended CC limit?

Comment: It really depends if you control or not what is generated. If yes, same limits as your code, if no, no limit. This is why we propose to make a distinction between JustMyCode and NotYourCode both code regions are treated differently by the rule system https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#NotMyCode